# ArangoDB - Is indexing better, than having more collections?

Tags: database, indexing, collections, arangodb

I have 3 types of entity:

- *Subjects*
- *Topics*
- *Tasks*

In each *subjects* there are *topics* and *tasks*. The *topics* can depend on each other. (Of course, a *topic* that belongs to *sj1 subject*, can only be depended on an another *topic* that also belongs to *sj1 subject*.)

Between *tasks* and *topics* there are connections (also must belong to same subject) that symbolise the fact that to solve a certain *task* we need to be aware of certain *topics*.

So a *task* can require more *topics*. Also a *topic* can be required by more *tasks*. ( N<--->M connection.)

What would be the best solution to store?

1. solution

   - Have 3 collections for each type of entity
   - In *tasks* and *topics* have an index for a subject identifier attribute.
   - and an edge collection for storing connections between *topics* [N]<-->[M] *tasks*
2. solution

   - Have 1 collection for the *subjects*
   - For each *subject*, have 1 *topics*, and 1 *tasks* collections. The connection between *subjects* and *tasks/topics* can be based on prefix of collection names. (I.e. for *chemistry* subject we have *chemistry_tasks* and *chemistry_topics* collections)
   - For each *subject*, have an edge collection for connections between the *tasks* and *topics* and an another edge collection for connections among topics (I.e. *chemistry_topics_tasks_connections* and *chemistry_topics_connections*)

   This way if I want to search among topics or tasks of a subject, I don't need to pre-filter them based on the subject identifier index. I'll immediately get the desired collection that contains all of my data. Moreover I don't have overhead of index for each document in *tasks* and *topics*.
   On the other hand, this will result in a mess of collections.

---

Sidenote: There will be maximum 50 subjects, but the number of tasks and topics are unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

In your terms, "awareness" is generated through the "graph", which requires no extra indexing to work at it's best.  ArangoDB automatically creates special "_key" and "_from/_to" indexes, which it uses for graph traversal.

But as for indexing, that about all search performance - indexes are added based on the data you want to find.  It really comes down to how you want to search:

- one collection with multiple entity types or
- multiple collections segregated by entity type.

**There is not a penalty for having large collections,** and a graph can link documents within a single collection - it doesn't need them to be segregated.  Also, you can have multiple edge collections and/or multiple document collections.  These are some of the concepts that challenge those of us who, like me, come from a traditional RDBMS - "schemaless" or "multi-model" databases kinda turn normalization on its ear.

Personally, I choose to build fairly large collections based on the data source (I import a data from external sources).  Each collection contains documents of multiple object/data schema identified by an `objType` attribute. The benefit here is that you can search all documents in the collection on a single field (or even an index with multiple fields, like `title` + `objType`), very quickly reducing the set of documents to iterate/traverse - *this* is usually where real performance gains are made.

So... I guess I recommend *solution #3*?

Comment: "There is not a penalty for having large collections" - As far as I know, the penalty comes from the fact, that if you use index on an attribute, then each record that is inserted into the collection will generate a record into the "index collection/table" as well. (Except for skiplist indexes if the document is missing that certain attribute.) This can be avoided with the 2nd solution, even though we are still able to search by subject with that approach.
Basically the question is, will I have any penalty by creating 200 collections?

Comment: @Woster - yes, index creation (or modifications due to insert/delete) is only a concern, but only if your collections are under heavy modification.  My systems (a 4-CPU VM running on OK-ish hardware, nothing special) takes less than 10 seconds to index 500K records (with 7 hash indices).  You might run into trouble with an ETL script that makes major mods to indexed fields (more than 50% of the records), but then maybe a truncate-and-reload or "collection swap" would be a better plan.

Comment: @Woster - no you should not have a penalty for having 200 collections, other than the time it takes to join/traverse edge collections.  If the number of edges is the same between the two concepts (200 collections or 1 collection), then there should be almost no performance difference in traversal in a single-server scenario (cluster is different, by nature).